# How to get two values from table based on different id's in same SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Users
=====================================
id, name, country_id, nationality_id

Countries
=====================================
id, name, currency
```

`country_id` and `nationality_id` both use id's from the Countries table.

`country_id` and `nationality_id` are not necessarily the same.

What I want to get is a table with the name of each user in a given country, the name of their country by `nationality_id` and the currency they use by `country_id`.

My problem is how to do the WHERE clause.  This is what I have but it is incorrect because the currency comes back by `nationality_id` instead of `country_id`.

Hope that makes sense....

```
SELECT
    Users.name,
    Countries.name,
    Countries.currency
FROM
    Users, Countries
WHERE
    Users.nationality_id = Countries.id 
AND Countries.id = 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use two joins against `Countries` with different alises, one for nationality_id and the other for country_id.

```
SELECT
    Users.name,
    /* name from the nationality_id join */
    cn.name,
    /* currency from the country_id join */
    cc.currency
FROM
    Users
      JOIN Countries cn ON Users.nationality_id = cn.id 
      JOIN Countries cc ON Users.country_id = cc.id 
WHERE 
    Users.country_id = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to join on to the `countries` table twice - once for the nationality and once for the resident country.  To give that, you use an alias, as in the query below.

```
SELECT
 users.*,
 nationality.name AS nationality,
 resident_country.currency
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN
  countries       AS nationality
    ON users.nationality_id = nationality.id
INNER JOIN
  countries       AS resident_country
    ON users.country_id     = resident_country.id
WHERE
  users.country_id = 6
```

You can then filter everything by the `users` table.  I filtered by resident country, you could change that to nationality by using `users.nationality_id = 6`, or whatever you liked.  If you needed to filter by the contents of the `countries` table, you filter by which ever alias is appropriate.

*(You can't reference the `countries` using `countries.???` because it has been given an alias every time it was used in the query.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Users u 
left join Countries c 
on c.id = u.nationality_id 
where c.id = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why would you do dat as in having 2 columns using same id from a different table
anyways this is how i would do it -

```
  SELECT Users.name, nt.name, curr.currency FROM
    Users
      JOIN Countries nt ON Users.nationality_id = nt.id 
      JOIN Countries curr ON Users.country_id = curr.id 
   WHERE 
    Users.country_id = 6
```